# React JS Reducer - Not able to do anything with the returned payload, only able to print

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm struggling with this issue for a few days straight now.

My reducer file:

```js
import {ADD_REPORT, GET_REPORTS, GET_REPORTS_ERROR, GET_REPORTS_SUCCESS} from "./ReportActions";

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    reports: [],
    isFetching: false,
    error: ''
};

export default function reportReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_REPORTS:
            return{
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
                error: ''
            };
        case GET_REPORTS_SUCCESS: // This is the part it's about.
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                reports: action.payload.reports,
                count: action.payload.reports.length
            };
        case GET_REPORTS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                error: action.payload.error
            };

        case ADD_REPORT:
            return {...state,
                reports: [...state.reportStore.payload,
                    {
                        id: action.report.id,
                        date: action.report.date,
                        city: action.report.city,
                        status: action.report.status
                    }]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**My output:**

[image]

As you can see, I'm not able to do anything with `action.payload.reports` or it will become empty.
The data is being fetched through React Saga, sent to the action and handled by the reducer.
When using hardcoded mock data that's following it does work:

```js
        case GET_REPORTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                reports: [{"id":14,"date":"24-10 13:28","city":"blabla","status":"unfixed"}],
                count: [{"id":14,"date":"24-10 13:28","city":"blabla","status":"unfixed"}].length
            };
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Inside `case GET_REPORTS_SUCCESS:` before the `return` statement, do a `console.log(action.payload);` and check the output

Comment: Can you show an exemple of your put actions ?

Comment: @DamirKasipovic Ase expected https://i.imgur.com/IIrKha8.png

Comment: You're wiping out the state in ADD_REPORT.

Comment: ```{ reports: [...state.reports, ...state.reportStore.payload], }```

Comment: @MaximeGirou My sagas file and actions: https://i.imgur.com/83wfLT5.png
@ DovRine I removed ADD_REPORT, yet it does the same

Comment: What would you get if you tried like this:
- Before return do `const reports = action.payload.reports`;
- Then inside return use `reports` and `reports.length` instead of `action.payload.reports`

Comment: @DamirKasipovic Done it: https://i.imgur.com/ZdCcpGX.png Still does exactly the same. When I touch the reports (const) variable, it'll be gone.

Comment: @S.A. good, it's obviously not gone, because in this example you're touching it only once (for `const` assignment) and it still reports `0`. Can you use `Object.keys(reports).length` for `length` and see what happens?

Comment: @DamirKasipovic Keeps showing the same: https://i.imgur.com/YAUZpcl.png I've never came across like something this strange

Comment: Since you're saying that the same reducer works correctly with hard-coded data and that you're using redux-saga, I suspect that you're accidentally returning an unresolved promise. Check the data in the saga before you send it to GET_REPORTS_SUCCESS to be sure that it's what you expect.

Comment: And, of course, make sure to check for the obvious things, like spelling mistakes in the payload keys.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(reports.length)` before return?

Comment: @ DamirKasipovic Also showing 0, but I think what @Dov Rine said is the direction I have to look into. Because if hardcoded mock data works, then there must be something wrong with the data that's being returned by saga. I will look into it and report back here later. Thank you all.

Comment: @S.A.: Btw, when you check the saga, make sure that the returned data doesn't accidentally have key name errors, too. I've been bitten by that before. So, some data sources work and others don't. The error may not even be in your client-side code at all...

Comment: @S.A.but in that case your reports would be blank too, not just it's length. To confirm your suspicion do `console.log(reports, reports.length)` before return and see what you get. If it was unfulfilled response, you'd have empty `reports` too most likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

Reporting back after researching what was wrong. The problem was that I returned an array before it was done fetching.

First I used yield call to make a fetch API request in another component, and use the result to work with. (ReportSagas.js)

```js
//Warning: This is not the solution, I'm explaining my fault first!
import { takeLatest, all, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import ReportService from '../../api/ReportList';

import {GET_REPORTS, getReportsSuccess, getReportsError} from "./ReportActions";

export function* getReportsSaga() {
    try {
        console.log("ReportSagas.js -> getReportsSaga() Try {}");
        const data = yield call(ReportService.getReports);
        yield put(getReportsSuccess(data));
        return data;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("ReportSagas.js -> getReportsSaga() Catch {}");
        yield put(getReportsError(error));
        return error;
    }
}

export function* watchGetReports() {
    yield all([takeLatest(GET_REPORTS, getReportsSaga)]);
}
```

The Fetch request looked like this.
And as you can see, the "reports" array was outside the scope and I returned it before the fetch was even finished. (api/ReportList.js)

```js
//Warning: This is not the solution, I'm explaining my fault first!
class ReportService {
    getReports = async () => {
        let reports = [];
        fetch('https://xxx/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(function(jsonResp) {
                jsonResp.forEach(function(reportItem) {
                    let report = {id: reportItem, date: reportItem.date, city: reportItem.city, status: reportItem.status};
                    reports.push(report);
                });
            });

        return reports;
    }
}

export default new ReportService();
```

So the solution I simply came up with, is to make the fetch request within the Sagas file like this, and it works fine! (ReportSagas.js)

```js
import { takeLatest, all, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import {GET_REPORTS, getReportsSuccess, getReportsError} from "./ReportActions";

export function* getReportsSaga() {
    try {
        console.log("ReportSagas.js -> getReportsSaga() Try {}");
        let data = yield fetch(`http://xxx/`);
        data = yield data.json();
        yield put(getReportsSuccess(data));
        return data;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("ReportSagas.js -> getReportsSaga() Catch {}");
        yield put(getReportsError(error));
        return error;
    }
}

export function* watchGetReports() {
    yield all([takeLatest(GET_REPORTS, getReportsSaga)]);
}
```

Comment: I see you're using `async/await` in your `getReport`, did you miss using `await` before fetch? So the function simply just awaits for the returning result

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that. All I had to do was add "await" and that solved this entire issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things here, which could be the issue.

In your `ADD_REPORT` case inside of your reducer.

Note: Please see the commented lines.

```
case ADD_REPORT:
            return {...state,
                 // 1st:
                // Your state doesn't have `reportStore` object
                // you could've misspelled the `state.reports` maybe
                // otherwise looking at this code, you're spreading something that doesn't exist
                reports: [...state.reportStore.payload,
                    {
                    //2nd:
                    // it should be action.payload.repord.id 
                    // same for the rest etc..
                        id: action.report.id,
                        date: action.report.date,
                        city: action.report.city,
                        status: action.report.status
                    }]
            };
```

Comment: It's not ADD_REPORT that's causing the problem, I removed it but it still gives the same result: https://i.imgur.com/CCZbq8i.png The issue is about GET_REPORTS_SUCCESS

Comment: Ohh. It could be the case that one of the other actions are getting dispatched again. Unknowingly. Which could reset the store. Please check if the `GET_REPORT_SUCCESS` is the last action called. You can use redux devtool to check.

Comment: It's most likely the data that's coming from Saga, because if it was something within the reducer it would've failed with hardcoded mock data as well. I'll look into it and report back here later. Thanks. :)